# OWLAPI wrongly using OBO parser for N-Triple file

Tags: java, maven, parsing, owl-api

We have a wrapper that parses ontologies using the OWLAPI.

But for some N-Triples ontologies the OWLAPI parser is failing when the wrapper is ran as a jar.

The parsed ontology is the following: http://www.cropontology.org/ontology/CO_320/Rice/nt

We are trying to parse it here: https://github.com/ncbo/owlapi_wrapper/blob/master/src/main/java/org/stanford/ncbo/oapiwrapper/OntologyParser.java#L637

We are facing 2 cases:

- When run through **mvn test**: the **parsing works** properly
- When run through the **jar**: it is **using the OBO parser**, generating a one axiom ontology where the whole nt ontology is contained as a string in a oboInOwl:http predicate:
  `<oboInOwl:http rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">//www.cropontology.org/rdf/CO_320:ROOT&gt; &lt;http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type&gt;`

In the 2 cases the OWLOntologyLoaderConfiguration and the input file are the same. So the only difference is that one is ran using `mvn test` and the other using `java -jar` (the 2 using the same java version)

I tried multiple things:

- Banning the OBO parser. I tried multiple syntax but none of them worked; the wrapper continue to use the OBO parser)

  ```
  conf.setBannedParsers("org.obolibrary.oboformat.parser.OBOFormatParser");
  conf.setBannedParsers("o.o.oboformat.parser.OBOFormatParser");
  conf.setBannedParsers("OBOFormatParser");
  ```
- Avoiding using different owlapi dependencies. Like documented here [OWLAPI: Parser not found if run from Jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43637343/owlapi-parser-not-found-if-run-from-jar) I tried using only owlapi-distribution to avoid any conflict

  ```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>net.sourceforge.owlapi</groupId>
    <artifactId>owlapi-distribution</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.1</version>
  </dependency>
  ```

Anyone have an idea where this inconsistency could come from?
Why is the OWLAPI loadOntologyFromOntologyDocument working properly in a case and wrongly in another? Even if the inputs are strictly the same.

**UPDATE1:**

The parsing of the NTriple file is, sometimes, failing because of some `_:genid1` nodes in the triples.
The problem is the following:

- When the app is packaged as a jar (with included dependencies) and the jar is run to parse the NTriple file. Then it fails returning `org.semanticweb.owlapi.rdf.turtle.parser.ParseException: Encountered " <PNAME_LN> ":genid1 ""`

The triple causing the problem is: `<http://www.cropontology.org/rdf/CO_320:0001563> <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#subClassOf> _:genid1.`

- When the exact same parser is run, on the exact same file, through a Maven test (the parser is called through a jUnit test and we run the test using `mvn test`). Then the parsing goes well. And the informations given by the `_:genid1` nodes are successfully extracted.

It looks like the OWLAPI is failing to parse a blank node in the first case.
I printed the OWLAPI version, using `VersionInfo.getVersionInfo()`, just before running `loadOntologyFromOntologyDocument`:

- For the jar version (that is causing the problem): `The OWL API (version 4.3.1)`
- For the test version (that is working): `The OWL API (version 4.3.1.2017-03-27T22:32:37Z)`

**UPDATE2:**

It seems like the problem comes from the jar building.

When the jar is built some dependencies are overwritten, so not all the parsers are included in the conf files

The org.openrdf.rio.RDFParserFactory in the jar only contains the following:

```
org.semanticweb.owlapi.rio.RioFunctionalSyntaxParserFactory
org.semanticweb.owlapi.rio.RioManchesterSyntaxParserFactory
org.semanticweb.owlapi.rio.RioOWLXMLParserFactory
org.semanticweb.owlapi.rio.RioFunctionalSyntaxParserFactory
org.semanticweb.owlapi.rio.RioManchesterSyntaxParserFactory
org.semanticweb.owlapi.rio.RioOWLXMLParserFactory
```

- When run through the test (where the parsing works), according to the log the ontology is in the `org.semanticweb.owlapi.formats.RioTurtleDocumentFormat`
- When run through the jar:

With NTriples files that don't have blank nodes (so the parser is working well) we got the following format: `org.semanticweb.owlapi.formats.TurtleDocumentFormat`

With NTriples files that have blank nodes we got:

```
The following parsers were tried:
1) org.semanticweb.owlapi.rdf.rdfxml.parser.RDFXMLParser@a4add54
2) org.semanticweb.owlapi.owlxml.parser.OWLXMLParser@71454b9d
3) org.semanticweb.owlapi.functional.parser.OWLFunctionalSyntaxOWLParser@67304a40
4) org.semanticweb.owlapi.rio.RioParserImpl : org.semanticweb.owlapi.formats.RioTurtleDocumentFormatFactory@95fd655c
5) org.semanticweb.owlapi.manchestersyntax.parser.ManchesterOWLSyntaxOntologyParser@61c9c3fd
6) org.semanticweb.owlapi.rio.RioParserImpl : org.semanticweb.owlapi.formats.NQuadsDocumentFormatFactory@6f9c39ad
7) org.semanticweb.owlapi.rio.RioParserImpl : org.semanticweb.owlapi.formats.RDFJsonDocumentFormatFactory@cd748dc3
8) org.semanticweb.owlapi.rio.RioParserImpl : org.semanticweb.owlapi.formats.NTriplesDocumentFormatFactory@937ecd36
9) org.semanticweb.owlapi.rio.RioParserImpl : org.semanticweb.owlapi.formats.TrigDocumentFormatFactory@27e81c
10) org.semanticweb.owlapi.rio.RioParserImpl : org.semanticweb.owlapi.formats.BinaryRDFDocumentFormatFactory@3bf24493
11) org.semanticweb.owlapi.rio.RioParserImpl : org.semanticweb.owlapi.formats.RDFJsonLDDocumentFormatFactory@dcacc47d
12) org.semanticweb.owlapi.rio.RioParserImpl : org.semanticweb.owlapi.formats.N3DocumentFormatFactory@9a5
13) org.semanticweb.owlapi.rio.RioParserImpl : org.semanticweb.owlapi.formats.RioRDFXMLDocumentFormatFactory@69b9a3bc
14) org.semanticweb.owlapi.rio.RioTrixParserFactory$TrixParserImpl : org.semanticweb.owlapi.formats.TrixDocumentFormatFactory@27e82d
15) org.semanticweb.owlapi.rdf.turtle.parser.TurtleOntologyParser@463b4ac8
16) org.semanticweb.owlapi.krss2.parser.KRSS2OWLParser@11981797
17) org.semanticweb.owlapi.rio.RioParserImpl : org.semanticweb.owlapi.formats.RDFaDocumentFormatFactory@264e8d
```

But for the RioTurtleDocumentFormat it says:

```
Parser: org.semanticweb.owlapi.rio.RioParserImpl : org.semanticweb.owlapi.formats.RioTurtleDocumentFormatFactory@95fd655c
    Stack trace:
org.openrdf.rio.UnsupportedRDFormatException: No parser factory available for RDF format Turtle (mimeTypes=text/turtle, application/x-turtle; ext=ttl)        
org.semanticweb.owlapi.rio.RioParserImpl.parse(RioParserImpl.java:207)
```

So it seems like the `RioTurtleDocumentFormatFactory` have not been properly included in the jar.

How could we make sure of that? It may come from the [pom.xml build](https://github.com/ncbo/owlapi_wrapper/blob/master/pom.xml#L139:L161)

**UPDATE3:**

I tried with only the owlapi-osgidistribution and I still got exactly the same error.

I also tried to package the jar using the maven-shade-plugin and get the same error.

After banning the OBO parsers log says it tried to parse the file using those parsers:

```
The following parsers were tried:
1) org.semanticweb.owlapi.rdf.rdfxml.parser.RDFXMLParser@2bb3058
2) org.semanticweb.owlapi.owlxml.parser.OWLXMLParser@6bbe2511
3) org.semanticweb.owlapi.functional.parser.OWLFunctionalSyntaxOWLParser@93cf163
4) org.semanticweb.owlapi.rio.RioParserImpl : org.semanticweb.owlapi.formats.RioTurtleDocumentFormatFactory@95fd655c
5) org.semanticweb.owlapi.manchestersyntax.parser.ManchesterOWLSyntaxOntologyParser@3d97a632
6) org.semanticweb.owlapi.rio.RioParserImpl : org.semanticweb.owlapi.formats.NQuadsDocumentFormatFactory@6f9c39ad
7) org.semanticweb.owlapi.rio.RioParserImpl : org.semanticweb.owlapi.formats.RDFJsonDocumentFormatFactory@cd748dc3
8) org.semanticweb.owlapi.rio.RioParserImpl : org.semanticweb.owlapi.formats.NTriplesDocumentFormatFactory@937ecd36
9) org.semanticweb.owlapi.rio.RioParserImpl : org.semanticweb.owlapi.formats.TrigDocumentFormatFactory@27e81c
10) org.semanticweb.owlapi.rio.RioParserImpl : org.semanticweb.owlapi.formats.BinaryRDFDocumentFormatFactory@3bf24493
11) org.semanticweb.owlapi.rio.RioParserImpl : org.semanticweb.owlapi.formats.RDFJsonLDDocumentFormatFactory@dcacc47d
12) org.semanticweb.owlapi.rio.RioParserImpl : org.semanticweb.owlapi.formats.N3DocumentFormatFactory@9a5
13) org.semanticweb.owlapi.rio.RioParserImpl : org.semanticweb.owlapi.formats.RioRDFXMLDocumentFormatFactory@69b9a3bc
14) org.semanticweb.owlapi.rio.RioTrixParserFactory$TrixParserImpl : org.semanticweb.owlapi.formats.TrixDocumentFormatFactory@27e82d
15) org.semanticweb.owlapi.rdf.turtle.parser.TurtleOntologyParser@784b990c
16) org.semanticweb.owlapi.krss2.parser.KRSS2OWLParser@13f17eb4
17) org.semanticweb.owlapi.rio.RioParserImpl : org.semanticweb.owlapi.formats.RDFaDocumentFormatFactory@264e8d
```

Here is the error log for the RioTurtleDocumentFormatFactory:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Parser: org.semanticweb.owlapi.rio.RioParserImpl : org.semanticweb.owlapi.formats.RioTurtleDocumentFormatFactory@95fd655c
    Stack trace:
org.openrdf.rio.UnsupportedRDFormatException: No parser factory available for RDF format Turtle (mimeTypes=text/turtle, application/x-turtle; ext=ttl)        org.semanticweb.owlapi.rio.RioParserImpl.parse(RioParserImpl.java:207)
        uk.ac.manchester.cs.owl.owlapi.OWLOntologyFactoryImpl.loadOWLOntology(OWLOntologyFactoryImpl.java:197)
        uk.ac.manchester.cs.owl.owlapi.OWLOntologyManagerImpl.actualParse(OWLOntologyManagerImpl.java:1156)
        uk.ac.manchester.cs.owl.owlapi.OWLOntologyManagerImpl.loadOntology(OWLOntologyManagerImpl.java:1112)
        uk.ac.manchester.cs.owl.owlapi.OWLOntologyManagerImpl.loadOntologyFromOntologyDocument(OWLOntologyManagerImpl.java:1068)
        org.stanford.ncbo.oapiwrapper.OntologyParser.findMasterFile(OntologyParser.java:708)
        org.stanford.ncbo.oapiwrapper.OntologyParser.internalParse(OntologyParser.java:651)
        org.stanford.ncbo.oapiwrapper.OntologyParser.parse(OntologyParser.java:630)
        org.stanford.ncbo.oapiwrapper.OntologyParserCommand.main(OntologyParserCommand.java:51)
No parser factory available for RDF format Turtle (mimeTypes=text/turtle, application/x-turtle; ext=ttl)        org.openrdf.rio.Rio.createParser(Rio.java:198)
        org.semanticweb.owlapi.rio.RioParserImpl.parseDocumentSource(RioParserImpl.java:241)
        org.semanticweb.owlapi.rio.RioParserImpl.parse(RioParserImpl.java:191)
        uk.ac.manchester.cs.owl.owlapi.OWLOntologyFactoryImpl.loadOWLOntology(OWLOntologyFactoryImpl.java:197)
        uk.ac.manchester.cs.owl.owlapi.OWLOntologyManagerImpl.actualParse(OWLOntologyManagerImpl.java:1156)
        uk.ac.manchester.cs.owl.owlapi.OWLOntologyManagerImpl.loadOntology(OWLOntologyManagerImpl.java:1112)
        uk.ac.manchester.cs.owl.owlapi.OWLOntologyManagerImpl.loadOntologyFromOntologyDocument(OWLOntologyManagerImpl.java:1068)
        org.stanford.ncbo.oapiwrapper.OntologyParser.findMasterFile(OntologyParser.java:708)
        org.stanford.ncbo.oapiwrapper.OntologyParser.internalParse(OntologyParser.java:651)
        org.stanford.ncbo.oapiwrapper.OntologyParser.parse(OntologyParser.java:630)
```

In the jar we can find the following classes (no multiple copies):

```
RioTurtleDocumentFormat.class
RioTurtleDocumentFormatFactory.class
RioTurtleParserFactory.class
RioTurtleStorerFactory.class
```

And in the `META-INF/services` directory we got:

```
META-INF/services/org.openrdf.rio.RDFParserFactory
META-INF/services/org.semanticweb.owlapi.io.LegacyOWLParserFactory
META-INF/services/org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLOntologyManagerFactory
META-INF/services/org.semanticweb.owlapi.io.OWLParserFactory
META-INF/services/org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLStorerFactory
META-INF/services/org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLDocumentFormatFactory
META-INF/services/org.openrdf.rio.LanguageHandler
META-INF/services/org.openrdf.rio.DatatypeHandler
META-INF/services/org.openrdf.rio.RDFWriterFactory
META-INF/services/com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory
META-INF/services/com.fasterxml.jackson.core.ObjectCodec
META-INF/services/org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
META-INF/services/javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer
```

The `META-INF/services/org.openrdf.rio.RDFParserFactory` contains:

```
org.semanticweb.owlapi.rio.RioFunctionalSyntaxParserFactory
org.semanticweb.owlapi.rio.RioManchesterSyntaxParserFactory
org.semanticweb.owlapi.rio.RioOWLXMLParserFactory
org.semanticweb.owlapi.rio.RioFunctionalSyntaxParserFactory
org.semanticweb.owlapi.rio.RioManchesterSyntaxParserFactory
org.semanticweb.owlapi.rio.RioOWLXMLParserFactory
```

The `META-INF/services/org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLDocumentFormatFactory` contains

```
org.semanticweb.owlapi.formats.BinaryRDFDocumentFormatFactory
org.semanticweb.owlapi.formats.N3DocumentFormatFactory
org.semanticweb.owlapi.formats.NQuadsDocumentFormatFactory
org.semanticweb.owlapi.formats.NTriplesDocumentFormatFactory
org.semanticweb.owlapi.formats.RDFaDocumentFormatFactory
org.semanticweb.owlapi.formats.RDFJsonLDDocumentFormatFactory
org.semanticweb.owlapi.formats.RDFJsonDocumentFormatFactory
org.semanticweb.owlapi.formats.RioRDFXMLDocumentFormatFactory
org.semanticweb.owlapi.formats.RioTurtleDocumentFormatFactory
org.semanticweb.owlapi.formats.TrigDocumentFormatFactory
org.semanticweb.owlapi.formats.TrixDocumentFormatFactory
org.semanticweb.owlapi.formats.BinaryRDFDocumentFormatFactory
org.semanticweb.owlapi.formats.N3DocumentFormatFactory
org.semanticweb.owlapi.formats.NQuadsDocumentFormatFactory
org.semanticweb.owlapi.formats.NTriplesDocumentFormatFactory
org.semanticweb.owlapi.formats.RDFaDocumentFormatFactory
org.semanticweb.owlapi.formats.RDFJsonLDDocumentFormatFactory
org.semanticweb.owlapi.formats.RDFJsonDocumentFormatFactory
org.semanticweb.owlapi.formats.RioRDFXMLDocumentFormatFactory
org.semanticweb.owlapi.formats.RioTurtleDocumentFormatFactory
org.semanticweb.owlapi.formats.TrigDocumentFormatFactory
org.semanticweb.owlapi.formats.TrixDocumentFormatFactory
```

So `org.semanticweb.owlapi.formats.RioTurtleDocumentFormatFactory` is actually listed in some of the `META-INF/services` files and the classes are included in the jar. But it still seems like the jar can't find it.

I don't really get how OWLAPI defines which parser to use and where to find them.

**UPDATE4:**

When I removing all excludes, and let the includes I still got a lot of lib that are excluded from the jar and then get `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`. I had to add several includes to fix that. But it still doesn't fix the problem (it just makes the log disappear)

Here is the plugin configuration I use:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.3</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>shade</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <artifactSet>
          <includes>
            <include>net.sourceforge.owlapi:owlapi-api</include>
            <include>net.sourceforge.owlapi:owlapi-apibinding</include>
            <include>net.sourceforge.owlapi:owlapi-fixers</include>
            <include>net.sourceforge.owlapi:owlapi-impl</include>
            <include>net.sourceforge.owlapi:owlapi-oboformat</include>
            <include>net.sourceforge.owlapi:owlapi-parsers</include>
            <include>net.sourceforge.owlapi:owlapi-rio</include>
            <include>net.sourceforge.owlapi:owlapi-tools</include>
            <include>commons-cli:*</include>
            <include>commons-io:*</include>
            <include>org.slf4j:*</include>
            <include>net.sourceforge.owlapi:owlapi-osgidistribution</include>
            <include>com.google.inject:*</include>
            <include>javax.inject:*</include>
            <include>com.google.*</include>
            <include>aopalliance:*</include>
            <include>org.openrdf.sesame:*</include>
            <include>org.tukaani:*</include>
            <include>net.sf.trove4j:*</include>
            <include>org.apache.commons:commons-csv</include>
          </includes>
        </artifactSet>
        <transformers>
          <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
            <mainClass>org.stanford.ncbo.oapiwrapper.OntologyParserCommand</mainClass>
          </transformer>
        </transformers>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

But it doesn't change anything in the `META-INF/services/org.openrdf.rio.RDFParserFactory` file in the jar

Maybe it is due to the fact that I needed to add `<include>net.sourceforge.owlapi:owlapi-osgidistribution</include>` and that is overwritting the RDFParserFactory file. But without including it I got a `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/semanticweb/owlapi/model/OWLAnnotationValue`

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues conspiring here:

- `OWLOntologyLoaderConfiguration` is an immutable class. Setters produce a modified object, not a change in the object they're called upon.
- There are two OBO parsers

To fix this, use:

```
conf = conf.setBannedParsers(
    "org.coode.owlapi.obo12.parser.OBO12ParserFactory org.semanticweb.owlapi.oboformat.OBOFormatOWLAPIParserFactory");
```

If you're using OWLAPI 5.1.0, you can set the banning at manager level:

```
manager.getOntologyConfigurator().withBannedParsers("...");
```

Another way to only use the parser you know must be used for a document is to set the format on the ontology source:

```
OWLOntologyDocumentSource source = 
    new FileDocumentSource(fileName, new NTriplesDocumentFormat());
```

This will only use parsers that match the requested format, rather than all the available parsers until one does not fail.

Update: the root error is related to attempting to parse NTriples with the turtle parser. The Rio ntriples parser should be selected instead - which is what I assume is happening with the maven test.
Most likely issue: the Rio parser is not included or its declaration is being skipped because of an issue in the meta-inf/services folder. Check if you have multiple copies of the stored list in the jar; only one will be loaded (multiple copies across multiple folders or multiple jars are fine for ServiceLoader, but multiple ones in the same jar are not).

Second update: your POM has multiple jars that contain parser lists. Try replacing

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>net.sourceforge.owlapi</groupId>
  <artifactId>owlapi-distribution</artifactId>
  <version>4.3.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>net.sourceforge.owlapi</groupId>
  <artifactId>owlapi-rio</artifactId>
  <version>4.3.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>net.sourceforge.owlapi</groupId>
  <artifactId>owlapi-compatibility</artifactId>
  <version>4.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

with

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>net.sourceforge.owlapi</groupId>
  <artifactId>owlapi-osgidistribution</artifactId>
  <version>4.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Update: I've checked out the project you use to replicate the issue. In order to debug it, I've tried adding the OWLAPI dependencies one at a time until the error stopped happening - in doing so, I've found that the content of this file:

`META-INF/services/org.openrdf.rio.RDFParserFactory`

should include

`org.openrdf.rio.turtle.TurtleParserFactory`

but it does not - it contains the contents of `owlapi-distribution/META-INF/services/org.openrdf.rio.RDFParserFactory`.

However, when you run this as a maven project, with maven resolved dependencies, the file `org.openrdf.rio.RDFParserFactory` appears twice: once in owlapi-distribution and once in sesame-rio-turtle (version 2.7.16 in this case); the second file contains the right factory.

The problem is that, in your repacking of owlapi-distribution and its dependencies, the files inside services are not merged as expected.

You should be able to fix that by using the shade plugin in your repacking. As an example, I'm pasting here what owlapi-distribution does - you'll need to change the exclusion list, as you probably don't want to exclude any of the dependencies.

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <artifactSet>
                            <includes>
                                <include>net.sourceforge.owlapi:owlapi-api</include>
                                <include>net.sourceforge.owlapi:owlapi-apibinding</include>
                                <include>net.sourceforge.owlapi:owlapi-fixers</include>
                                <include>net.sourceforge.owlapi:owlapi-impl</include>
                                <include>net.sourceforge.owlapi:owlapi-oboformat</include>
                                <include>net.sourceforge.owlapi:owlapi-parsers</include>
                                <include>net.sourceforge.owlapi:owlapi-rio</include>
                                <include>net.sourceforge.owlapi:owlapi-tools</include>
                            </includes>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>org.apache.felix:org.osgi.core</exclude>
                                <exclude>org.openrdf.sesame:*</exclude>
                                <exclude>com.fasterxml.jackson.core:*</exclude>
                                <exclude>com.github.jsonld-java:*</exclude>
                                <exclude>com.fasterxml.jackson.core:*</exclude>
                                <exclude>org.apache.httpcomponents:*</exclude>
                                <exclude>commons-codec:commons-codec:*</exclude>
                                <exclude>org.slf4j:*</exclude>
                                <exclude>org.semarglproject:*</exclude>
                                <exclude>com.google.guava:*</exclude>
                                <exclude>com.google.inject:*</exclude>
                                <exclude>javax.inject:*</exclude>
                                <exclude>aopalliance:*</exclude>
                                <exclude>com.google.inject.extensions:*</exclude>
                                <exclude>com.google.code.findbugs:*</exclude>
                                <exclude>org.slf4j:slf4j-api</exclude>
                                <exclude>commons-io:*</exclude>
                                <exclude>org.tukaani:*</exclude>
                                <exclude>net.sf.trove4j:*</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                        </artifactSet>
                        <transformers>
                            <transformer
                                implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer" />
                        </transformers>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: Thanks. We knew for the immutable, what was missing was the OBO parser class name. It helped me getting the root of the problem.
I updated the question to provide details on the problem

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now that I know where it comes from I will check how to configure the pom.xml to make sure the Rio parser is loaded

Comment: I think the problem might be that you've got multiple jars providing the same file. See my update for a fix.

Comment: I checked it and all the files are unique. I tried the owlapi-osgidistribution and still got exactly the same problem. I have put more details on jar content (especially META-INF/services) as an update of the original question

Comment: I think I've found the actual root cause by checking out your project.

Comment: Thanks! I tried packaging it with the includes. 
But even when I remove all excludes, and let the includes I still got a lot of lib that are excluded from the jar and then get `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`. 
I had to add several includes to fix that. But it still doesn't fix the problem (actually it just make the log disappear)
I detailed the includes added in the original post.

But is it normal that we have to play that much with the includes just to get the Turtle parser working on a regular OWLAPI build?

Comment: It's not normal - what's unusual is the repacking into a flattened jar. It's not a tested configuration.

Comment: I've opened a pull request to discuss possibilities https://github.com/ncbo/owlapi_wrapper/pull/6

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! I tried with this bundling: it's avoiding the creation of double in the RDFParserFactory services file but doesn't add Factory (still only `RioFunctionalSyntaxParserFactory`, `RioManchesterSyntaxParserFactory`, `RioOWLXMLParserFactory`).
What would be the good way to have a well packaged jar that is working everywhere? (like a black box, without depending on the computer environment, just needing Java to run it properly)

Comment: In the end we will bypass this problem by converting the ntriples as RDF/XML file before using our owlapi_wrapper.